# Reusing a merged development branch / Remerging into an unchanged stable branch with git

Tags: git, merge, github, branch

Two programmers, A & B, are working on a project with a github hosted repo:

Branch master exists.

Programmer A creates devBranchA based on the latest master

```
master$ git checkout -b devBranchA
```

Programmer B creates devBranchB based on the latest master

```
master$ git checkout -b devBranchB
```

They decide to merge stable changes into master whenever possible.

The agreed workflow is:

[on devBranch]

```
git commit -m 'Stuff to make branch stable enough to merge'

git checkout master

git pull origin master 

git merge devBranch [fix merge conflicts if any]

git checkout devBranch

git commit -m 'New cool stuff'
```

However, if there have been no commits to master since the last merge, it is then not possible to merge the devbranch back into master (unless a new dev branch was created, rather than the old one reused)

In this case, when Programmer B comes to merge his work into the master branch, it will not be the current intended master, but the state of master before the merge.

Is there a way to automatically force the master branch to update itself to the head of the dev branch on merge if there have been no interim commits?

What is the intended multi-user workflow when working with git and a centralised github repo? I feel as though I am not using git as it is intended to be used.

Comment: “Is there a way to automatically force the master branch to update itself to the head of the dev branch on merge […]?” – I don’t really get that. When the dev branch was changed, and you get checkout `master` and merge the dev branch into it, then `master` should change, even when there were no explicit commits on `master`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `git fetch;git rebase origin/master` or `git pull --rebase`, both honor the order of the commits in the master repository because it rebases, sticking local commits on top.  You don't care about the order of the local commits as much on local branches anyway because only you have them.  Try it out, but use with care, e.g. duplicate a branch before rebasing until you're used to it.

In general, you're talking about git workflow, and I've found that there are two general workflows that you should get familiar with.  Be aware that I'm talking from personal experience on how to minimize conflicts:

- Rebase-first workflow (for cleanest commit history, pushes the burden of conflicts generally to uncommitted code)
- Merge workflow (sometimes simpler when there are a lot of changes that would conflict, I usually use this only as a fallback)

### Example Initial workflow

```
git checkout master // For the sake of argument, let's say the latest commit in your local master is from august 1st or something old like that.
git branch temp_branch // copy of the master
git checkout temp_branch
git add changedFiles;git commit changedFiles; // A change from november 2nd.

git log // Now your dev branch has a new commit on top of an otherwise old branch.

git log origin/master // You get a listing of the commits from the origin repository, the master branch.
```

Generally I use origin/master for development staging, with git tags standing for the commits that are made live releases.

Now here's where the problem occurs, and where the choice of workflow comes into play: let's say there's a commit that came from another dev repository up in master, e.g. a commit from october 15th.  Maybe it was commited by another developer, maybe by yourself.

Your choices: Merge or rebase.

### Merge

Introduces an extra commit, honors your local (unpushed) branched dev history over the canonical (origin/master) history, causes a little more potential for conflicts **for others and other branches**.  Essentially you're saying "my commit order will be mixed with the master branch commit order" as opposed to reordering commit history.

```
git merge origin/master // merge commit introduced
... // Resolve any conflicts, and finalize the merge commit.
git checkout master;git rebase temp_branch // Move the changes to master.
git push origin/master // Pushing changes, including merge commit, to origin/master
```

At the end, commit history will look something like:  August-October-November-MergeCommit

### Rebase

No extra commits, honors commits already in the canonical repository (origin/master) over local commits, conflicts that occur will generally occur on commits that the developer has not yet commited (and thus no-one else can account for).

```
git rebase origin/master // 
... // Resolve any conflicts...
git rebase --continue or git rebase --abort
... // Resolve any conflicts...
git checkout master;git rebase temp_branch // Get the branch changes without a merge commit into master.
git push // Push all changes to the canonical repository.
```

Note: If you end up having to do more than two conflict resolutions, -then- it is a good time to `git rebase --abort` and fall back to doing a merge.

---

Try out the process, see if it makes sense for you!  It takes some experimentation before you can really get tactics that work well for your development in git, I guess because there are so many more approaches once you get decentralized.

Comment: Will this have any adverse effect if I am pushing each dev branch commit to github?

Or are you saying I should be working locally on master, and performing a rebase based on the latest remote master? Please forgive my idiocy.

Comment: Generally, I rebase everything, so it just becomes a question of what I'm using as the solid/unmoving base for various branches.  I use origin/master as the canonical, most solid branch, on top of which all commits lie.  But when a branch isn't commited yet, e.g. origin/dev then I'd just continue linearly committing to that, and `git rebase origin/dev` in the rarer event that multiple commits from different sources to a central development branch happen.  As a result, master is pretty much always a linear copy of origin/master (just on my local machine)...

Comment: And whenever I want to make code live, I go: `git rebase origin/master`, `git checkout master`, `git rebase temp_branch`, `git push`, and have a completely linear commit history that I can stack on top of the origin/master branch for a fast-forward pulldown of the commits.

Answer (score 0):

You can find another illustration of the two workflow mentioned by [Tchalvak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69993/tchalvak) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7982217/6309) in "[git rebase vs git merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804115/git-rebase-vs-git-merge/804178#804178)".

As explained in "[What is the right git workflow with shared feature branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927566/what-is-the-right-git-workflow-with-shared-feature-branches/12927985#12927985)", I prefer avoiding "back-merge" (from `master` to `devBranch`), and would rather rebase `devBranch` on top of `master`, provided that:

- `devBranch` is regularly merged to master
- I rebase only new local commits (that I haven't pushed yet).